# sqoop import changes ownership : hive table displays NULL values in columns

Tags: hive, sqoop

I have a table `orders_1` with 300 records and I want to load data into hive table.

When I ran the sqoop hive-import command, table data was loaded in the /hive/warehouse/ location.But the user ownership has changed and **I'm facing the issue when I am querying the hive table to view the loaded table data.It displays all the columns with NULL values.**

```
sqoop-import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/retail_db --username root --password cloudera --table orders_1 --hive-import --hive-database my_sqoop_db --hive-table hive_orders1 --hive-overwrite --fields-terminated-by '\t' --lines-terminated-by '\n' -m 1;
```

*Output :*

```
INFO hive.HiveImport: Loading uploaded data into Hive

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-common-0.13.1-cdh5.3.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
OK
Time taken: 1.039 seconds
Loading data to table my_sqoop_db.hive_orders1
chgrp: **changing ownership** of 'hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/my_sqoop_db.db/hive_orders1/part-m-00000': User does not belong to hive
Table my_sqoop_db.hive_orders1 stats: [numFiles=1, **numRows=0**, totalSize=12466, rawDataSize=0]
OK
```

*FYI* , with the same user **root** the first time I was able to do sqoop hive-import and view the data in hive and do hive operations.

I could not figure out what went wrong. Can anybody please help me in resolving this issue ?

[image: Hive_table with NULL values]

[image]

Comment: If the cluster is not kerberized, then just set `export HADOOP_USER_NAME=hive` before running sqoop. That way the HDFS files will be created directly with owner `hive`. But I'm not sure that will address the root cause.

Comment: I have tried out with your suggestion.Still facing same issue.

Comment: Huh - so you *really* can access the file but the records appear to be empty. Did you inspect the HDFS files that sqoop has created (size & content)?

Comment: on cloudera VM, the username and password for retail_db is 
`--username=retail_dba`  &`--password=cloudera \` , why are you using root?

Comment: The sql data is loaded into hive location.Not sure whether the issue I'm facing is due to changed ownership.